# Why does Node crypto return different values for the same string?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptography

I am trying to run this program:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var a = crypto.createHash('md5').update('89Zr-J591').digest('hex');
var name = '89Zr−J591';
var b = crypto.createHash('md5').update(name).digest('hex');

console.log(a); //c6281bc77bea86a92df59225357b6b54
console.log(b); //a3853813486b53eca6bf7d2428876161
console.log(a === b); //false
```

I expect both `a` and `b` to be `true`... to be the same.

Why is this not the case? Why are they different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not the same string, see the hyphen:

```
'89Zr-J591'
//   ^ this is U+002D
'89Zr−J591'
//   ^ this is U+2212
```

```
% charinfo −-
U+2212 MINUS SIGN [Sm]
U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS [Pd]
```

In the first example [`U+002D`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/002D/index.htm) is used. Which is what you get when pressing minus on your keyboard.

In the second example [`U+2212`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2212/index.htm) is used.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize this because when I queried both of them in my Oracle database they would return the same row even though they are different hypens. I wonder how Oracle handles hyphens... I guess it is coalescing them somehow?

Comment: @kidcapital When something like this happens. A hexdump and diff is a go to method for me :-)